# data not appending to new line. getting inserted into last line and creating new columns

Tags: python, csv

I have written some code in python that is used to append rows into a csv file. However, my code enters it into the same line, creating new columns.

I want to append the updated list into my csv file.

```
update=[uptime,downtime,partsproduced,partsrem,pred]
with open("m.csv","a") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(update)
    print("Data has been recorded and updated in the input file")
```

Comment: Is `update` a single row to be appended or five rows for uptime,downtime,partsproduced,partsrem,pred?

Comment: it would be useful to understand your question if you could give us example file content before and after the append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should try something like this

```
update=[uptime,downtime,partsproduced,partsrem,pred,"\n"]
```

Answer (score 1):

While opening file use newline parameter, like below

```
with open("m.csv","a",newline='') as csvfile:
```